# Bash Syntax Error Missing expecting "then"

Tags: bash, make, makefile

For the following lines in my Makefile I get the error

```
Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting "then")
```

Code:

```
if [ ! -d upload-api/app-router/ ] then
    git clone someRepo upload-api/app-router/
fi
```

I've tried with a semicolon after the brackets but I get still the same error

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to put then in next line or use semicolon

```
if [ ! -d upload-api/app-router/ ] 
then
```

or

```
if [ ! -d upload-api/app-router/ ];then
```

Comment: Note that the spaces before and after `;` are optional, `if [ ! -d upload-api/app-router/ ];then` (or any combination) is equally valid.

Comment: Totally agree ...

Answer (score 4):

In the context of a makefile, I see two things.

First, you need a semicolon or newline before the `then`.  Shell syntax for `if` looks like: `if commands... ; then commands... ; fi` (where any semicolon here can be replaced with a newline).

Second, when `make` executes a recipe, it runs each individual line of the recipe in a separate shell instance, and stops executing if any single line gives an error.  Effectively, it's running:

```
sh -c 'if [ ! -d upload-api/app-router/ ]; then' &&
    sh -c 'git clone someRepo upload-api/app-router/' &&
    sh -c 'fi'
```

...which is a syntax error on the first line, with or without the semicolon, because the `if` is never finished.

So for a makefile recipe, you would need to let `make` know that it should treat the entire `if ... fi` block as one line.  For instance, use backslashes for line continuation, and semicolons in the appropriate places since the shell won't see any line breaks.

```
my-target:
↦       if [ ! -d upload-api/app-router/ ] ; then \
↦           git clone someRepo upload-api/app-router/ ; \
↦       fi
```

This gets unwieldy pretty quickly, so my preferred solution is usually to put the shellscript in a separate file, then run that file from your recipe.